# Find enum value by enum name in string - Python

Tags: python, enums

I'm struggling with Python enums. I created an enum class containing various fields:

```
class Animal(Enum):
   DOG = "doggy"
   CAT = "cute cat"
```

I know that I can access this enum with value i.e. by passing `Animal("doggy")` I will have `Animal.DOG`. However I would like to achieve the same but the other way around, let's say I have `"DOG"` and I use it to find `"doggy"`.

Example:

```
str_to_animal_enum("DOG") = Animal.DOG
```

I thought that I could rewrite **init** function of Enum class to check whether string name that we put as a parameter has representants in Enum names, if yes then we have a match.

Sth like this:

```
def __init__(cls, name):
   for enum in all_enums:
      if enum.name == name:
         return enum
```

But this solution looks very heavy in computation. Let's say that I have 100 names to find and for each name we have to make N iterations in the worst case scenario where N is number of enums in enum class.

I think there should be something better but I just don't know what. Do you have any ideas how it could be implemented? Thanks :)

Comment: This isn't really how you are supposed to use enums, I would say. Enums are just constants that are more practically named; you appear to want to use them a bit like a (constant) dictionary, with a reverse look-up.

Comment: Yes you're completely right I didn't see that. Thank you for your help!

Comment: The question is indeed a valid use case. E.g. say you're converting an environment variable value into an Enum. It is a common enough use case that Java supports it with a  `valueOf(String name) method for all enums. Also it's not a duplicate

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As per [the manual](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/enum.html#programmatic-access-to-enumeration-members-and-their-attributes):

```
>>> Animal.DOG.value
'doggy'
>>> Animal.DOG.name
'DOG'
>>> # For more programmatic access, with just the enum member name as a string:
>>> Animal['DOG'].value
'doggy'
```